# Error for TronBox initialization or command related to TronBox

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, tron

I am completely new to **Tron**. I need to deploy contract using **TronBox**. I am following steps from this link https://developers.tron.network/docs/tron-box-user-guide. for command `tronbox init` it is giving following error:

> /home/administrator/.nvm/versions/node/v6.16.0/lib/node_modules/tronbox/build/cli.bundled.js:1733
>   tronWrap._getNetworkInfo = async function () {
>                                      ^^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
>       at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)

Somebody knows what I am missing or what installations are compulsory for **tronbox**?

Answer (score 0):

Giving my own question's answer. 
I checked my node version using `node -v`, it gives v6.16.0. I download and install node version 10. Tried the following commands:

```
 nvm install 10
 nvm use 10
```

Again installed tronbox by using `npm install -g tronbox`. Then Created a new directory in which I initialize tronbox. Got Success!!